# Spring Security Acl Level Class Permission

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, acl, spring-security-acl

Does **Spring Security Acl** support class-level permissions? For example, let's suppose I have an `Asset` class, and I want to allow read permissions to all instances of the `Asset` class to any user with role `ROLE_USER.` As long as I could see, `ObjectIdentityImpl` only accepts object instances.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Spring Security ACL is not really handy for this. I would suggest you use a pre-authorize annotation instead:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public List<Asset> getAllAssets();
```

Make sure you have pre- and post-annotations enabled in your configuration.

Answer (score 3):

The `org.springframework.security.acls.model.ObjectIdentity` is one of the core Spring Security ACL interfaces representing the identity of an individual domain object to secure. It imposes type and identifier properties. If you need class level permissions, you can use  e.g. "Class" as a type and actual class name as an identifier (e.g. "Asset" or "my.package.Asset").

Depending on a concrete scenario, it may be also needed to implement `org.springframework.security.acls.model.ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategy` and `org.springframework.security.acls.model.ObjectIdentityGenerator` interfaces accordingly.